# How to generate SOAP API for java from a web service written in C#?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wsdl, glassfish

I’m having a C# web service and I would like to generate Java API for it from wsdl address.

I’m looking for a freeware way to do it.

So far I managed to generate the API with Intellij Ultimate using Glassfish.

Is there any free way/software to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `wsimport` tool, which is part of the Metro project. Metro is the project which implements JAX-WS for GlassFish.

There's a blog post covering how to parse a WSDL from a URL endpoint and generate the Java code from it, reproduced below:

> ```
> C:\>wsimport -keep -verbose http://compA.com/ws/server?wsdl
> parsing WSDL...
>
> generating code...
> com\mkyong\ws\ServerInfo.java
> com\mkyong\ws\ServerInfoImplService.java
> ```

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

You can find the `wsimport` tool in your GlassFish installation here:

```
glassfish4/glassfish/bin/wsimport
```